# Are pinned public keys in the Network Security Configuration file trusted even if the CA that issued it is not?

Tags: android, ssl, certificate-authority, certificate-pinning, public-key-pinning

Let's say that I have an app that transmits some sensitive info to my server.  I want to reduce the risk of a man-in-the-middle attack on my users, so I pin the keys used by my server in the [Network Security Configuration file](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config).

But, let's say a user of my app does not trust the CA that issued our certificate, and has removed it from the list of trusted CAs, or maybe an OS update removes the CA because it has been found to be behaving badly.

Ideally, in such a case I would like my app to refuse to connect to the server.  I only want it to make the connection if the certificate presented by the server is signed with a key in the pinset **AND** comes from a CA that is trusted by the OS/user.  Does pinning a key in the network security config file accomplish this?  Or, are pinned keys trusted no matter what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HPKP instructs the browser to store the signature for your server certificate for the period of time you specify. Using HPKP does not replace the standard certificate validation.

In your scenario the pinned PK in the browser will be valid for the server certificate your server is presenting, but the actual certificate validation will fail since the CA is not trusted.

Comment: I'd just like to clarify - this is not a browser (by the typical definition), but a mobile app, and there are some differences in the key/cert pinning mechanics compared to what a web developer might be used to.  Is your knowledge specific to Android apps?  If so, could you point to some documentation about it?

Comment: @duggulous You are correct, there are some differences between standard web browsers and mobile apps. I have experience with both standard web development and android app development. My experience from android development is a couple of years old, but using HPKP with self signed certificates that wasn't trusted, much like your untrusted CA example, didn't work. Unfortunately I can't find a lot of documentation on the subject.